# Combining data from two different API and parsing the response (nodes typescript)

Tags: arrays, typescript, parsing, object

I'm currently working on a RESTful API backend using nodejs with typescript where I need to gather information from multiple different APIs and parse the result and pass on the parsed information to the frontend.
Right now I'm working on a API route where I gather information from two different external API routes, I gather the data from there with https. I send the data onward to my Objecthandler in the form [object Object],[object Object] because I push the response from my first http call into an array and my second http response into another array which I then push onto a third array that is the combined data from both responses.

```
const first: object [] = [
];
const second: object [] = [
];
const combined: object [] = [
];
```

My object handler code looks like this:

```
function ObjectHandlerAvainsanat(obj: any): object[] {
const keywords: object [] = [
];
if (obj instanceof Array) {
obj.forEach((e: any) => {
const results = e.results.map((x: any) => x);
const vals = {
localname: results.localname,
prefLabel: results.prefLabel,
altLabel: results.altLabel,
};
keywords.push(vals);
});
return keywords;
}
}
```

However, I get the error that

```
const results = e.results.map((x) => x);
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

The actual data inside the http response looks like this, where I want the values from inside the results object array:

```
{
"@context": {
"skos": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#",
"isothes": "http://purl.org/iso25964/skos-thes#",
"onki": "http://schema.onki.fi/onki#",
"uri": "@id",
"type": "@type",
"results": {
"@id": "onki:results",
"@container": "@list"
},
"prefLabel": "skos:prefLabel",
"altLabel": "skos:altLabel",
"hiddenLabel": "skos:hiddenLabel",
"@language": "FI"
},
"uri": "",
"results": [
{
"uri": "http://www.yso.fi/onto/yso/p22020",
"type": [
"skos:Concept",
"http://www.yso.fi/onto/yso-meta/Concept"
],
"localname": "p22020",
"prefLabel": "pyydystä ja päästä -kalastus",
"lang": "fi",
"altLabel": "catch and release -kalastus",
"vocab": "yso"
},
{
"uri": "http://www.yso.fi/onto/yso/p22337",
"type": [
"skos:Concept",
"http://www.yso.fi/onto/yso-meta/Concept"
],
"localname": "p22337",
"prefLabel": "CATCH-22",
"lang": "fi",
"vocab": "yso"
}
```

Does anyone here know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for all the help,
Br,
Victor

Comment: Please format your code

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

`e.results` is `undefined`. This is a fact irrespective of your result object you are showing.

## Fix

`console.log(e)` and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

(assuming e is your http response)

Based on the HTTP response you provided, e is a JSON object, so you can call:

```
let newVar = JSON.parse(e);
```

and then try to pull results using:

```
newVar.results.map((x: any) => x);
```

Hope this helps...